# Proper way to put comments in build events command line?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What's the proper way to put comments into the pre/post build event command line?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use REM: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php

An example:

```
REM signtool sign /a $(TargetPath)
xcopy /Y "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Deploy\$(TargetFileName)"
```

Comment: for VS2017, had to use `::` instead

Comment: REM worked fine for me in VS2019

Answer (score 65):

You can also use double colons ::

```
:: My comments
xcopy /Y "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Deploy\$(TargetFileName)"
```

I prefer these to the REM keyword in command line (and bat files).

Comment: VS2017 recognizes `::`, not `REM` unfortunately

Comment: In turn, with `dotnet publish` even this does not work. I ended up using `echo `...'` which is not comment per se, but at least does the job.

Comment: @astrowalker `cmd /C rem text`, perhaps?